# angularjs store login information

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a web-based application and I'm starting to work on the settings portion of my app. I'm trying to stay away from using global variables but I want to keep a record of the information that was used to login so that I can show it on the settings screen (sans password).

What's the recommended way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get started you can store it in the `$rootScope`, which is inherited by all other scopes in the application (or available directly through `$rootScope`).

Depending on how complex your app will be (or if you're writing tests), you may want to consider isolating your authentication/user management into a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Check out [this helpful repo](https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning#authentication) for Angular learning resources.

Comment: Service is definitely the place for this.

Comment: Your link to docs lead me to: http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app/

Comment: @Jackson Glad I could help.  Don't stop at one article, Angular is a very flexible framework so there are often many solutions to the same problem. You may find one that is more elegant or appealing to your specific situation.